# python call type using variable

Tags: python, django

The following works fine:

```
import someapp.models

dump_data(someapp.models.MyModel, using='dumpingdb')
```

But this does not work:

```
import someapp.models

modelType = MyModel
dump_data(someapp.models.modelType, using='dumpingdb')
```

Any idea how to store the model name in a variable and then call it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you writing in your second option is that you trying to import `modelType` from `someapp.models` which doesn't exist.

In the second one you need to import that model and just call that variable name in dump_data:

```
from someapp.models import MyModel

modelType = MyModel
dump_data(modelType, using='dumpingdb')
```

or :

```
import someapp.models

modelType = someapp.models.MyModel
dump_data(modelType, using='dumpingdb')
```